# SonarQube report points to localhost on GitLab

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube

Hello I have set up CI/CD on my project using SonarQube, my SonarQube is hosted on a server and GitLab connects to it, but for some reason after the analysis is finished it posts a summary of the analysis as a comment on merge request but the link is directed to localhost:9000 not my server link where the analysis can actually be accessed.

[image]

how could I make it point to my server link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure the server public URL:

- Log in to the SonarQube dashboard and click on the `Administration` tab
- Browse to the `Configuration → General settings → General` menu
- Under the `General` section, change the `Server base URL` to the public URL
- Save the changes

Copy-pasted from: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/sonarqube/administration/configure-domain/