# Sonarqube comment on MR Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci, sonarqube-scan, merge-request

[image]

I'm trying to integrate Sonarqube's comment into GitLab's MR. But Unable to find a concrete document to do so. Attached is the reference on localhost

I tried multiple methods to pick merge_requests in GitLab-ci.yml but not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SonarQube report points to localhost on GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70927548/sonarqube-report-points-to-localhost-on-gitlab)

Comment: @sytech Thanks for the reply. The issue was due to MR decoration in gitlab-ci.yml. I configured correctly and then it worked. 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html#configure-pipelines-for-merge-requests